# Сделать массив на основе другого массива и его повторяющихся значений

Tags: php, битрикс

**Доброго времени суток.**
В массиве есть повторяющиеся значения, как на основе них сделать один массив?
То есть в первом массиве есть клиент который купил 2 товара, соотвественно когда перебираю данный массив в `foreach`, то выводит товары данного клиента в отдельных массивах.

**Вот текущий первый массив**:

```
Array
(
    [CLIENT_NAME] =>  ivanov,
    [CLIENT_EMAIL] => ivanov@example.com,
    [PRODUCT_NAME1] => Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017), 32GB, Black,
    [DETAIL_PAGE_URL] => /catalog/phone/smartfony/smartfon-samsung-galaxy-a5-2017-32gb-black/,
    [LID] => s2,
    [FUSER_ID] => 26503134,
),
Array
(
    [CLIENT_NAME] => ivanov,
    [CLIENT_EMAIL] => ivanov@example.com,
    [PRODUCT_NAME] => Наушники Samsung EO-PN920CBEGRU,
    [DETAIL_PAGE_URL] =>/catalog/phone/naushniki/naushniki-samsung-eo-pn920cbegru/,
    [LID] => s2,
    [FUSER_ID] => 26503134,
)
```

**Мне нужно из текущего первого массива сделать массив следующего вида:**

```
Array
(
    [CLIENT_NAME] =>  '',
    [CLIENT_EMAIL] => ivanov@example.com,
    [PRODUCTS] => array(
        'PRODUCT_NAME1' => Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017), 32GB, Black,
        'PRODUCT_NAME2' => Наушники Samsung EO-PN920CBEGRU,
    ),
    [DETAIL_PAGE_URLS] => array(
        'DETAIL_PAGE_URL1' => /catalog/phone/smartfony/smartfon-samsung-galaxy-a5-2017-32gb-black/,
        'DETAIL_PAGE_URL2' => /catalog/phone/naushniki/naushniki-samsung-eo-pn920cbegru/
    ),
    [LID] => s2,
    [FUSER_ID] => 26503134
)
```

Как это сделать, ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, а то застрял.

Надеюсь смог донести свою мысль.

Comment: @maxkrasnov, спасибо что подкорректировали внешний вид вопроса =). А как сделали?

Comment: `products` и `detail_page_urls` в один массив сложите, а то из одной шляпы другая получится

Comment: есть кнопка "Правка", но если не путаю, то зависит все от рейтинга

Comment: Я при оформлении вопроса, использовал форматирование которое в редакторе, но что то так как у вас не получилось =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$arClients = [];
foreach($arOrders as $arOrder) {
  $arClients[$arOrder['FUSER_ID']]['CLIENT_NAME'] = $arOrder['CLIENT_NAME'];
  $arClients[$arOrder['FUSER_ID']]['CLIENT_EMAIL'] = $arOrder['CLIENT_EMAIL'];
  $arClients[$arOrder['FUSER_ID']]['PRODUCTS'][] = [
       'PRODUCT_NAME' => $arOrder['PRODUCT_NAME'],
       'DETAIL_PAGE_URL' => $arOrder['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']
  ];
}
```

Ну и по аналогии остальные поля, тут идет привязка к `FUSER_ID`, может `DETAIL_PAGE_URL` лучше в `PRODUCTS` же, рядом с `PRODUCT_NAME`?

Comment: только что заметил в ассоциативном масиве ключи 1, 2 и т.п. это принципиально и удобно ли использовать?

Comment: Это не принципиально, мне бы собрать в отдельный массив пользователей и их приобретенные товары. Просто у кого то может быть один, у кого то несколько.

Comment: тогда поправил ответ, лучше вот так

Comment: А на счет того что бы DETAIL_PAGE_URL в PRODUCTS, тоже можно. Даже лучше будет. =)

Comment: пытюась теперь из получившего массива, сделать просто html вывод, например:<p>$item['CLIENT_NAME']</p>, <a href="$item['PAGE_URL']">$item['PRODUCT_NAME']</a>

Comment: я перебираю циклом foreach() по массиву $arClients['PRODUCTS']. Но т.к. в нем есть вложенные массивы то нужно указать $arClients['PRODUCTS'][index] но как это сделать динамично, что то не получается

Comment: все сделал. =)))

Answer (score 2):

не надо соединять эти массивы. у вас все поля кроме двух, содержащих информацию о товаре, одинаковы.

За основу возьмите первый элемент массива.

```
$result = current($data);
```

Далее верните массив пар товар-ссылка

```
$result['products'] = array_map(function($v){
                         return ['title' => $v['PRODUCT_NAME'], 
                                 'url' => $v[...]];
                      }, $data);
```

ну и можете удалить лишнее

```
 unset($result['PRODUCT_NAME'], ...);
```

либо в начале можете извлечь нужные поля:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($data, array_flip(['client_name', ...]));
```